# Grails testing Curl like post

Tags: grails, curl

I tend to test my API using Curl.

Is there a way in Grails that I can make a test just posts to my API and then I can evaluate the results.

I have tried Spock testing and this didn't work.

I cannot seem to find a simple example on the internet.

Has anyone done similar?

Comment: This question may be a  result of the frustration from the previous question, BUT POST can be tested in spock. Have to try some more.:) On the other hand if you just wanted a tool similar to curl but easy to use the refer REST Console extension in Chrome.

Comment: "I have tried Spock testing and this didn't work." - It may be that you tried something that didn't work but certainly Spock can work and does.  In recent versions of Grails we include Spock as the default unit testing framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of testing you want to do.  If you want to send requests to your app using curl you can.  I do that for a lot of things.  If you want automated tests, you can do that too.  Spock is the default unit testing framework but you could use others.

See the controller unit testing docs at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers.  There are examples there which show how to test different HTTP request methods, JSON and XML request bodies, JSON and XML responses, AJAX, mime types, etc.

I hope that helps.